# Amazon C# request.FeedContent.Position = 0 error "Cannot Access a Closed File"

Tags: c#, amazon-mws, dynamics-nav

I am trying to get the SubmitFeed working using the C# dll and a flatfile (not xml).  The language is C/AL for a Microsoft ERP system called Dynamics NAV.  Here is my code:

```
config := config.MarketplaceWebServiceConfig();

config.ServiceURL := 'https://mws.amazonservices.com';

service := service.MarketplaceWebServiceClient(MyAccessKey,MySecretKey,'NAV','1.0',config);

request := request.SubmitFeedRequest();

request.Merchant := 'mymerchant';

request.Marketplace := 'MyMarketPlaceID';

request.FeedContent := SystemIOFile.Open('C:\Test\Jason.txt',FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read);

request.ContentMD5 := service.CalculateContentMD5(request.FeedContent);

request.FeedContent.Position := 0;

request.FeedType := '_POST_INVENTORY_AVAILABILITY_DATA_';

response := service.SubmitFeed(request);
```

The request.FeedContentPosition := 0 line is where the error is that says "Cannot Access a Closed File"

I have submissioncount and submissionresult totally working, I just can't get submitfeed to work.

I have followed other C# examples and they seem to be the same, anyone have thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out.  This line is what closes the file:

```
request.ContentMD5 := service.CalculateContentMD5(request.FeedContent);
```

I believe this is a bug in C/AL (NAV) as I can write similar code in c# and it 
totally works.

My work around is to create a 2nd instance of the request and just grab the MD5 value from the first request.  Something like this works:

```
request := request.SubmitFeedRequest();    
request.Merchant := "Merchant No.";    
request.FeedContent := SystemIOFIle.Open('C:\Test\Jason.txt',FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read);    
MD5Value := WSClient.CalculateContentMD5(request.FeedContent);
CLEAR(SystemIOFIle);    
CLEAR(request);        
request2 := request2.SubmitFeedRequest();    
request2.Merchant := "Merchant No.";    
request2.FeedContent := SystemIOFIle.Open('C:\Test\Jason.txt',FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read);

request2.ContentMD5 := MD5Value;    
request2.FeedContent.Position := 0;    
request2.FeedType := '_POST_FLAT_FILE_PRICEANDQUANTITYONLY_UPDATE_DATA_';    
response := service.SubmitFeed(request2);
```